# Display Partial view page content in a page on button click

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

This is my index view page.

```
<div>
Hello world
</div>
@section footerButton{
    <input type="button" id="button1" value="Button1"/>
}
```

This is my Layout page.

```
<div id="divFooter">
    @RenderSection("footerButton", required:false)
    </div>
```

This is my Partial View page.

```
<h2>This is partial page</h2>
```

My requirement is, after run the project when i click on the button, the partial page content will get displayed.

Comment: Either put your partial in a hidden div, and handle the buttons click event to display it, or use ajax to call a server method that returns the partial and update the DOM

Comment: @StephenMuecke, can you please help me with the code sir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: Include the partial in a hidden element in the view and handle the buttons `.click()` event to display it

Html

```
<div id="mypartial">
  @Html.Partial("_YourPartial")
</div>
```

Script

```
$('#button1').click(function() {
  $('#mypartial').show();
});
```

CSS

```
#mypartial {
  display: none;
}
```

Option 2: Use ajax to call a server method that returns the partial view and update the DOM

Html

```
<div id="mypartial"></div>
```

Script

```
var url = '@Url.Action("YourMethod")';
$('#button1').click(function() {
  $('#mypartial').load(url);
});
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult YourMethod()
{
  return PartialView();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton sir. Two of your options worked fine. Thanks a ton again.